# Open datasets for product reviews

Tags: data-request, sentiment-analysis, products

Are there public repositories that have public reviews and feedback data of products (I need digital camera reviews to be specific)

After searching on the internet, I found http://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/sentiment-analysis.html#datasets

Are there other sources of reviews data available on the internet or I will have to crawl and mine websites myself?

Comment: To be specific, I'm looking for free datasets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Amazon has an API for this](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html), and then there's always web-scraping.

Answer (score 5):

We have several product reviews indexed at https://www.datafiniti.net.  Here is a search for every product we have with reviews: [link](https://www.datafiniti.net/search/products?%5B%7B%22i%22%3a%22reviewHeaderInput%22,%22v%22%3atrue%7D%5D).  Many reviews have text, title, date, rating, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a dataset of Amazon product reviews - nearly 150 reviews spanning 8 years across various products http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find [Amazon reviews webdata 1995-2013](https://archive.org/details/amazon-reviews-1995-2013) data on archive.org.

> This dataset consists of reviews from amazon. The data span a period of 18 years, including ~35 million reviews up to March 2013. Reviews include product and user information, ratings, and a plaintext review. Note: this dataset contains potential duplicates, due to products whose reviews Amazon merges. A file has been added below (possible_dupes.txt.gz) to help identify products that are potentially duplicates of each other.

Answer (score 0):

There is an opendata set stored in Amazon S3 that you could use. This contains information from over 160 million customer reviews between 1995 and 2015 currently.

You can find more information on it at https://registry.opendata.aws/amazon-reviews/, and I've written a LinkedIn article showing some analysis results (and the steps to repeat that analysis) [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/100-shades-grey-other-amazon-review-discoveries-mark-chopping/).